# OLEDB gives an error while trying to fetch data

Tags: c#, oledb

When I tried to select all data from excel using OLEDB.I get an error of

**Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'Created By'**
Is this because of that space in the column name?

The query is:

> SELECT Code,Name,Created By,Date FROM [Template$]

```
public DataTable GetExcelDataToTable(string filename, string dataExchangeSelectedColum)
{
    //List<DataExchangeDefinition> dataExchange = new List<DataExchangeDefinition>();
    string extension = Path.GetExtension(filename);
    string connstring = string.Empty;
    DataTable ExcelData = null;
    try
    {
        switch (extension)
        {
            case ".xls":
                connstring = string.Format(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel03ConString"].ConnectionString, filename);
                break;
            case ".xlsx":
                connstring = string.Format(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel07+ConString"].ConnectionString, filename);
                break;
        }
        using (OleDbConnection connExcel = new OleDbConnection(connstring))
        {
            using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand())
            {
                cmd.Connection = connExcel;
                connExcel.Open();
                var dtExcelSchema = connExcel.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
                connExcel.Close();
                var firstSheet = dtExcelSchema.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT " + dataExchangeSelectedColum + " FROM [" + firstSheet + "]";
                ExcelData = new DataTable();
                OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter();
                oda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                oda.Fill(ExcelData);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }

    return ExcelData;
}
```

This is the code I tried, here `dataExchangeSelectedColum` contains the columns they are "Code, Name, Created By, Date"

Comment: What is the **exact** value of `cmd.CommandText` when the exception occurs?

Comment: **Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'Created By'** is the error

Comment: The error comes when there is a space given for the column name, why?

Comment: Does you connection string include HDR = YES?  It the first row of worksheet the column names?

Comment: @jdweng yes it contain HDR=YES

Comment: Can you try `SELECT Code,Name,[Created By],Date FROM [Template$]`?

Comment: @vc74 ok, i will try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add square brackets around the column name if it contains spaces:

```
cmd.CommandText = $"SELECT [{dataExchangeSelectedColum}] FROM [{firstSheet}]";
```

EDIT after your comment:

If you want to select several columns which name may contain spaces:

```
public DataTable GetExcelDataToTable(string filename, IEnumerable<string> columns)
{
    ...
    string formattedColumns = string.Join("," columns.Select(column => $"[{column}]"));

    cmd.CommandText = $"SELECT {formattedColumns} FROM [{firstSheet}]";
    ...
}
```

which can be invoked the following way:

```
DataTable table = GetExcelDataToTable(fileName, 
    new string[] { "Code", "Name", "Created By", "Date" });
```

Comment: let me try with this one

Comment: Thank you very much let me try with this

Answer (score 1):

I have done it like this

```
 List<string> selecttedColsList = dataExchangeSelectedColum.Split(',').ToList();
        string formattedColumns = "";
        //string comma = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < selecttedColsList.Count; i++)
        {
            //formattedColumns = string.Join(",", selecttedColsList.Select(col => $"[" + selecttedColsList[i] + "]"));
            formattedColumns+= ""+$"[" + selecttedColsList[i] + "]";
            if (i != selecttedColsList.Count - 1)
            {
                formattedColumns += ",";
            }

        }
```